# Check Java Enabled in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to check if java is installed in Web browser or not. If yes i have to open applet and if not i'll open a Popup.
i Used

```
if(navigator.javaEnabled()){
}
```

It is working fine in firefox and crome but in IE it always returns true. Please suggest if there is any alternate for IE.

Comment: [JavaScript is *not* Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that simple.

This app will generate minified javascript that will enable Java detection (and if needed, version detection as well): http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/download/

The code is pretty long, and the short answer is that a simple javaEnabled() won't work in IE.